# Google play error after updating 4.0.4?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, motorola-xoom

I have some problems with google play after updating to 4.0.4 on my Motorola xoom. The store doesn't open and gives **Server error**!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unbind the gmail account.
2. Clear Google Play data.
3. Bind the Gmail account.